# How to get ng-table header value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get the table header for each column from JavaScript, however calling `tableTest` only returns data of each row of column, is there a way to return the header like 'name' and 'description'. Maybe sort of `tableTest.data-title`

```
<table ng-table="tableTest">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="sample in $data">
      <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">
          {{sample.name}}
      </td>
      <td data-title="'Description'" sortable="'description'">
          {{sample.description}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting these headers dynamically? Because what I can see from this code is that they're static and they won't change in your code. So you can just use them as they are displayed here.

Comment: The column header is static, however lets say I want to add these headers into an array and I have more than 10 header columns, I do not want to add each column header 1 by 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a doing it through `javaScript`?

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6QpOXluKBHi03ogkqffq?p=preview) code

**HTML**

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="sample in $data">
            <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">
                {{sample.title}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Description'" sortable="'description'">
                {{sample.description}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    //gets table
    var oTable = document.getElementById('myTable');

    //gets rows of table
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

    //loops through rows    
    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {

        //gets cells of current row  
        var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;

        //gets amount of cells of current row
        var cellLength = oCells.length;

        //loops through each cell in current row
        for (var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++) {

            // get your cell info here

            var cellTitle = oCells.item(j).getAttribute("data-title");
            document.write("Header for Row#" + j + " : " + cellTitle + "<br>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Output**

```
Header for Row#0 : 'Name'
Header for Row#1 : 'Description'
```

Comment: @nicker Look at the first line of my code and your code. There's a difference. I've added an `id` attribute `<table ng-table="tableParams" id="myTable">`. Have you made that change in your code?

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it.

Comment: I'd solve the earlier problem it's due to `i` not declared in the for loop i added `var i` in the loop at it'd solved.